# Open a PopupWindow and let the outsides still touchable

Tags: android, popupwindow

How to open a PopupWindow on Android and let all the others components touchable without dismiss the PopupWindow?

This is how it's created:

```
public class DynamicPopup {
    private final PopupWindow window;
    private final RectF rect;
    private final View parent;
    private final RichPageView view;

    public DynamicPopup(Context context, RichPage page, RectF rectF, View parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
        rect = rectF;

        window = new PopupWindow(context);

        window.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
        window.setWidth((int) rect.width());
        window.setHeight((int) rect.height());
        window.setTouchable(true);
        window.setFocusable(true);
        window.setOutsideTouchable(true);

        view = new RichPageView(context, page, false);
        window.setContentView(view);

        view.setOnCloseListener(new Listener(){
            @Override
            public void onAction() {
                window.dismiss();
            }
        });


    }

    public void show() {
        window.showAtLocation(parent, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, (int) rect.left, (int) rect.top);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this method? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#setOutsideTouchable%28boolean%29

Comment: @ernazm, you should move this to an answer.

Comment: Well I'm not sure this method works as intended since I havn't used it (android SDK has a lot of buggy stuff tbh) and this question has been raised.

Comment: I added the code I already using, setOutsideTouchable(true) doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per javadocs

> Controls whether the pop-up will be informed of touch events outside of its window. This only makes sense for pop-ups that are touchable **but not focusable**

So your line

```
 window.setFocusable(true);
```

causes the method `setOutsideTouchable()` to do nothing.

Comment: Even with window.setFocusable(false); this closes by default

Answer (score 12):

just like the ernazm say

> As per javadocs
>
> Controls whether the pop-up will be informed of touch events outside of its window. This only makes sense for pop-ups that are touchable **but not focusable**

and it's work on

```
window.setTouchable(true);
window.setFocusable(false);
window.setOutsideTouchable(false);
```

When window touchalbe is true, focusable is false, setOutsideTouchable() is work, if setOutsideTouchable(true), touch outside of popupwindow will dismiss, otherwise the outside of popupwindows still can be touchable without dismiss.

Comment: `setTouchable()` is by default `true`. and `setOutsideTouchable()` is by default `false`. So all you really need to set is `setFocusable(false)`. But it seems event listeners don't work on views inside the popup when its not focusable.

Comment: It's a bit tricky.  The docs are right on but for some reason, I always want to set focusable to true.  The above three setting work.

Comment: my event listener for spinners works but my edittext listener does not.

Answer (score 1):

For that you have to made the Custom Popup window. In that u have to call the another layout. So in this way You can access the other component also.
It just the One type of the Layout. But you can set its appearence as Popup Window.

```
<!-- POPUP MENU -->
    <RelativeLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/popup_window"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/fullwindowborderforpopup"
        >



        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"

            android:padding="1px"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            android:background="@drawable/borderforpopup"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="vertical" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dip"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dip">

                <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/tital_of_popup"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Event Registration"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" 
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="vertical" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dip"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dip"
            >

                <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/message_of_popup"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:text="Please fill all the data" 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:textStyle="normal"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="9dip"
                >


             <Button 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:id="@+id/okbutton" 
                android:text="OK" 
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:shadowColor="#000000"
                android:gravity="center" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonborderframe"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

try this. And you can hide and show the layout whenever you want. And other fields are accessable.

Comment: I really need to add PopupWindows on runtime, I don't have then until it's runnning.

Comment: Then you should have to implement the custom style for the popup window and set the property as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your code:

```
window.setOutsideTouchable(true);
```

From the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#setOutsideTouchable(boolean)):

> ```
> void setOutsideTouchable (boolean touchable)
> ```
>
> Controls whether the pop-up will be informed of touch events outside of its window. This only makes sense for pop-ups that are touchable but not focusable, which means touches outside of the window will be delivered to the window behind. The default is `false`.
>
> If the popup is showing, calling this method will take effect only the next time the popup is shown or through a manual call to one of the `update()` methods.