# Avoiding PopupWindow dismissal after touching outside

Tags: android

I would like to use a PopupWindow with following behaviours/features:

- It is focusable (has interactive controls inside eg. buttons)
- The View 'under' popupwindow has to consume the touches outside the popup properly
- .. but the popupwindow has to stay on screen even after clicking outside

I've found bunch of posts regarding PopupWindow but none of them asked question how to deal with such situation..

I think I tried every possible combination of setOutsideTouchable(), setFocusable(),setTouchable() but I'm stuck. Popup deals with clicks on it properly, but it's dismissed always when touching outside.

My current code is :

```
View.OnTouchListener customPopUpTouchListenr = new View.OnTouchListener(){

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
        Log.d("POPUP", "Touch false");
        return false;
    }

};


LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
LinearLayout layout= (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.insert_point_dialog, null);
PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(layout,400,200,true);
pw.setOutsideTouchable(true);
pw.setTouchable(true);
pw.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
pw.setTouchInterceptor(customPopUpTouchListenr);
pw.showAtLocation(frameLayout, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
```

My general goal is to create a floating window which behaves like a 'tools palette' in software like gimp: has some controls inside, stays on top until closed by 'X' button, and allowing to interact with controls outside-under it..
Maybe there's some better way to do this, not a PopupWindow? But I still haven't found more suitable control.

Answer (score 11):

Nothing suggested here, or elsewhere seemed to work for me.  So I did this:

```
popupWindow.setTouchInterceptor(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                if (motionEvent.getX() < 0 || motionEvent.getX() > viewWidth) return true;
                if (motionEvent.getY() < 0 || motionEvent.getY() > viewHight) return true;

                return false;
            }
        });
```

If the touch is within the bounds of the popupWIndow, the touch event not consumed (so buttons or scrollviews will work).  If the touch is outside the bounds, the touch is consumed and not passed to the popupWindow so it is NOT dismissed.

Comment: Thank you! All the other answers either locked out my EditText fields, or made the popup transparent, or allowed click-outside to dismiss my popup!

Answer (score 6):

Just remove `pw.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());`

Answer (score 6):

it's too late but for people who google this stuff
just change the order of lines

```
pw.showAtLocation(frameLayout, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
pw.setOutsideTouchable(true);
pw.setTouchable(true);
pw.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
pw.setTouchInterceptor(customPopUpTouchListenr);
```

instead of

```
pw.setOutsideTouchable(true);
pw.setTouchable(true);
pw.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
pw.setTouchInterceptor(customPopUpTouchListenr);
pw.showAtLocation(frameLayout, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
```

putting anything after showatlocation method makes it like nothing there

Answer (score 2):

pw.setOutsideTouchable(false);

Comment: No that works the same (popup disappears after clicking outside, getting into onTouch). As stated here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271784/open-a-popupwindow-and-let-the-outsides-still-touchable) focusable popups ignore setOutsideTouchable setting.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
pw.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution is:

popupWindow.setFocusable(true);

popupWindow.update();

Thanks to:
http://android-er.blogspot.ch/2012/04/disable-outside-popupwindow-by.html

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you must figure out that why the popupWindow is dismissed when you touch outside.

After read the source code of PopupWindow and the resource file styles.xml,

```
<style name="Widget.PopupWindow">
    <item name="popupBackground">@drawable/editbox_dropdown_background_dark</item>
    <item name="popupAnimationStyle">@style/Animation.PopupWindow</item>
</style>
 <style name="Widget">
    <item name="textAppearance">?textAppearance</item>
</style>
```

So there is nothing like the dialog theme:

```
<style name="Theme.Dialog">
<item name="windowCloseOnTouchOutside">@bool/config_closeDialogWhenTouchOutside</item>
</style name="Theme.Dialog">
```

But Somethings happen  when PopupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable() is called,

```
private void preparePopup(WindowManager.LayoutParams p) {
    if (mContentView == null || mContext == null || mWindowManager == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("You must specify a valid content view by "
                + "calling setContentView() before attempting to show the popup.");
    }

    if (mBackground != null) {
        final ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = mContentView.getLayoutParams();
        int height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        if (layoutParams != null &&
                layoutParams.height == ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT) {
            height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        }

        // when a background is available, we embed the content view
        // within another view that owns the background drawable
        PopupViewContainer popupViewContainer = new PopupViewContainer(mContext);
        PopupViewContainer.LayoutParams listParams = new PopupViewContainer.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, height
        );
        popupViewContainer.setBackgroundDrawable(mBackground);
        popupViewContainer.addView(mContentView, listParams);

        mPopupView = popupViewContainer;
    } else {
        mPopupView = mContentView;
    }
    mPopupViewInitialLayoutDirectionInherited =
            (mPopupView.getRawLayoutDirection() == View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_INHERIT);
    mPopupWidth = p.width;
    mPopupHeight = p.height;
}
```

A container view "PopupViewContainer" is created.

```
 private class PopupViewContainer extends FrameLayout {
    private static final String TAG = "PopupWindow.PopupViewContainer";

    public PopupViewContainer(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (mTouchInterceptor != null && mTouchInterceptor.onTouch(this, ev)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        final int x = (int) event.getX();
        final int y = (int) event.getY();

        if ((event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                && ((x < 0) || (x >= getWidth()) || (y < 0) || (y >= getHeight()))) {
            dismiss();
            return true;
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) {
            dismiss();
            return true;
        } else {
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    }
```

}

Now you know the reason which matters.
So there are two ways in which you can aviod PopupWindow dismissal after touching outside.
1.just as @Raaga did. remove pw.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());

2. you can implement a OnTouchListener to filter the touche events outside the PopupWindow.

Comment: So it seems that if you want to be able to interact with the rest of the view, and have the popup window focusable, the only solution is to implement your own popup window :/

Answer (score 1):

There is an unconventional solution: override the `dismiss` to block it to call `super.dismiss`, then create a custom method to control dismiss, here is example code:

```
class XXXPopupWindow(
    val context: Context
) : PopupWindow() {

    init {
        //some your own logic initialization
        isOutsideTouchable = true
        isTouchable = true
        isFocusable = false
    }


    override fun dismiss() {
        //avoid click outside will dismiss this, use close when want to dismiss this
    }

    fun close(){
        super.dismiss()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to setFocusable(false) for PopupWindow

buttons still be clickable, but without visual clicking behaviour (some custom handler to force show click?)

below is sample for floating window with "always on top" option

original layout near floating window is fully operational in both cases, moreover, it is possible to use dialogs and other popups when window is still floating

also the window is reusable

```
final static int buttonAlpha = 0xDF;
final static float buttonTextSize = 12f;

public final void addPopupButton(LinearLayout linearLayout, String title, android.view.View.OnClickListener onClickListener)
{
    Button button = new Button(this.getContext());
    button.setText(title);
    button.setTextSize(buttonTextSize);
    button.getBackground().setAlpha(buttonAlpha);
    button.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    linearLayout.addView(button, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
}

public final Button addPopupCheckbox(LinearLayout linearLayout, String title, boolean isChecked, android.view.View.OnClickListener onClickListener)
{
    final Button button = new Button(getContext());
    button.setText(title);
    button.setTextSize(buttonTextSize);
    final int buttonHeight = button.getHeight();
    setButtonChecked(button, isChecked);
    button.setHeight(buttonHeight);
    button.getBackground().setAlpha(buttonAlpha);
    button.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    linearLayout.addView(button, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    return button;
}

public final void setButtonChecked(Button button, boolean isChecked)
{
    button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier(isChecked ? "android:drawable/btn_check_on" : "android:drawable/btn_check_off", null, null), 0, 0, 0);
}

private boolean isMenuAlwaysOnTop = true;
private PopupWindow popupWindowMenuV2 = null;

public final void popupMenuNav2()
{
    if (popupWindowMenuV2 == null)
    {
        // [start] layout

        ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(this.getContext());

        final LinearLayout linearLayoutNavigation = new LinearLayout(this.getContext());
        linearLayoutNavigation.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        linearLayoutNavigation.setBackgroundColor(0x7FFFFFFF);
        linearLayoutNavigation.setPadding(20, 10, 20, 10);

        scrollView.addView(linearLayoutNavigation, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        popupWindowMenuV2 = new PopupWindow(this);
        popupWindowMenuV2.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
        popupWindowMenuV2.setWidth(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        popupWindowMenuV2.setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        popupWindowMenuV2.setTouchable(true);
        popupWindowMenuV2.setOutsideTouchable(!isMenuAlwaysOnTop);
        popupWindowMenuV2.setFocusable(!isMenuAlwaysOnTop);
        popupWindowMenuV2.setTouchInterceptor(new OnTouchListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {
                if ((event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE)
                {
                    if (!isMenuAlwaysOnTop)
                        popupWindowMenuV2.dismiss();
                    else
                        return false;
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        popupWindowMenuV2.setContentView(scrollView);

        // [end] layout

        // [start] always on top checkbox

        final Button buttonMenuAlwaysOnTop = addPopupCheckbox(linearLayoutNavigation, "always on top", isMenuAlwaysOnTop, null);
        buttonMenuAlwaysOnTop.setOnClickListener(
                new OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View vv)
                    {
                        isMenuAlwaysOnTop = !isMenuAlwaysOnTop;
                        setButtonChecked(buttonMenuAlwaysOnTop, isMenuAlwaysOnTop);
                        popupWindowMenuV2.dismiss();
                        popupWindowMenuV2.setOutsideTouchable(!isMenuAlwaysOnTop);
                        popupWindowMenuV2.setFocusable(!isMenuAlwaysOnTop);
                        popupWindowMenuV2.showAtLocation(((Activity) getContext()).getWindow().getDecorView(), Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL + Gravity.RIGHT, 0, 0);
                    }
                });

        // [end] always on top checkbox

        addPopupButton(linearLayoutNavigation, "some button",
                new OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View vv)
                    {
                        if (!isMenuAlwaysOnTop)
                            popupWindowMenuV2.dismiss();
                        someAction();
                    }
                });

    }

    popupWindowMenuV2.showAtLocation(((Activity) getContext()).getWindow().getDecorView(), Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL + Gravity.RIGHT, 0, 0);
}

// somewhere in handler:
            if (someCondition)
            {
                if (popupWindowMenuV2 != null && popupWindowMenuV2.isShowing())
                    popupWindowMenuV2.dismiss();
                else
                    popupMenuNav2();
                return true;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

popupWindow.setFocusable(false);

popupWindow.update();

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).