# how to perform an action inside a scrollview while scrolling?

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a scroll view, where a small graph pop up is there. When i click on button,pop up comes out, and when i touch again the screen it gets dismissed. I want to pop up to be dismissed as soon as i start scrolling screen.But its get dismiss on first scroll and then screen starts scrolling in second.

```
profileScrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChanged() {

            }
        });
```

Comment: If you want to keep your popup when you press outside try looking at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406339/avoiding-popupwindow-dismissal-after-touching-outside)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    yourView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

   @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
              int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

  }

@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  switch(scrollState) {

        case 0: // SCROLL_STATE_IDLE 
        popup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        break;

        case 1: // SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL 
        popup.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        break;

        case 2: // SCROLL_STATE_FLING 
        popup.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        break;      

        default:
         //show popup here
        popup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        break;
        }
    }
 });
```

Comment: i have a scroll view how can i use on scroll listner